# SQL Update with a concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table of data:

```
Description   | LongDescription  | rn
TEST                 ERIC           1
TEST                 KEN            2
TEST                 JIM            3
TEST                 TOM            4
```

I want to be able to say where rn=1 and LongDescription=Eric concatenate the LongDescriptions of rn 1 and 2 - using an Update statement so end up with

```
Description   | LongDescription  | rn
TEST                 ERIC - KEN     1
TEST                 KEN            2
TEST                 JIM            3
TEST                 TOM            4
```

Also need to mention that there is more data than listed above so there will be more instances of rn being 1 and 2 etc

Is this even possible?

Comment: It would help if you showed multiple rows in your sample data where `rn=1` and provided the logic by which the "ERIC" row is chosen for update over say the "KEN" row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE desc_table 
SET desc_table.longdescription = desc_table.longdescription+'-'+b.longdescription
FROM desc_table
INNER JOIN desc_table b
ON desc_table.rn = b.rn-1
```

Comment: Thanks, with a bit of tweaking this got me wher I needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
update tbl
set LongDescription= LongDescription +'-'+(select LongDescription from tbl where rn=2)
where rn=1
```

Comment: Ah, I shoukd have mentioned that the table has more data than the example data, so when I run this query i get the sub-query returned more than 1 value

Comment: So, what is the criteria to select the value LongDescription?

Comment: at the minute I delete all entries in the table where rn <>1 to return the most current record for each user, there is also a user column, but I'd like to be able to do the above whenever the LongDescription=Ken (this will occur more than once) before I do that

Answer (score 0):

```
Update SomeTable
Set LongDescription = Stuff(
                        (
                        Select ' - ' + T1.LongDescription
                        From SomeTable As T1
                        Where T1.rn = SomeTable.rn
                        Order By <add sorting here>
                        For Xml Path(''), type
                        ), 1, 2, '' )
Where SomeTable.PrimaryKeyCol = (
                                Select TOP 1 T2.PrimaryKeyCol
                                From SomeTable As T2
                                Where T2.rn = SomeTable.rn
                                Order By T2.LongDescription
                                )
```

The above is an outline of a solution. What is required is the logic by which the correct row for update is chosen. In the above solution, I simply chose the first value for each `rn` value by a simple alphabetic sort.